# Oracle Apex Canvas to blob in PNG format saved to item

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, canvas, oracle-apex

I am struggling to convert my canvas URL to a blob format, specifically in PNG format. The DataURL is generating quite perfectly when I tested it without the conversion code, the problem comes in when trying to convert it to Blob. I am using an html button that triggers the JavaScript function with the ID buttonTextArea.

I need the Blob file to be linked to my APEX page item, which I use the $s('P9_IMAGE_CODE', Blob) format, which also works when I tested it using text only. Once the page is processed, that item will be sent into a blob column within my table.

Here is my code:

```
$("#buttonTextArea").click(function(dataURL) {
var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
var canvas  = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
       var parts = dataURL.split(',');
       var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
       var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);

         return new Blob([raw], {type: contentType});
}

         var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
         var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
         var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
         var rawLength = raw.length;

         var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

            for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
            uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}

     return new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: contentType});
     document.getElementById("textArea").value = dataUrl;


    $s('P9_IMAGE_CODE', Blob); --P9_IMAGE_CODE IS THE ITEM ON MY PAGE
```

});

I have been trying examples from :
https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/blob/master/README.md
and
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67587

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "Blob" you're referring to is this thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob which doesn't convert into a string for $s like that. It's not the same as an Oracle BLOB. I suspect you'll need to write some more code (e.g. use FileReader or something, I don't know) to convert it into a format suitable for posting to Apex.

Comment: yup, this might be a good starting point for you http://www.talkapex.com/2012/08/how-to-sendupload-clob-from-browser-to.html

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffrey pointed out, the javasscript "Blob" is not the same as the Oracle BLOB datatype.

The toDataURL function is already returning a base64 encoded string, so what you'd need to do is to save that string and then after submit convert it into a real blob. 
Sending it to the database may be a bit of an issue since there is a limit of 32k bytes on an item's content. This means you'll likely have to send the string in chunks to the database. This is then not a VARCHAR2 (which also has a limit of 32k) but a CLOB.
 As Wesley points out, there are some workarounds for that. [The blog he linked to](http://www.talkapex.com/2012/08/how-to-sendupload-clob-from-browser-to.html) is one such example. There is also [a plugin to facilitate the handling of clobs in apex](http://www.enkitec.com/products/plugins/clob-load).

Once you get the base64 string to the database, you'll have to convert it to a real blob. There is no built-in to quickly do this, but once again this is something several people have already solved. 
[A script is provided here](http://oracle-base.com/dba/script.php?category=miscellaneous&file=base64decode.sql) by Tim Hall to convert a CLOB to a BLOB.

So:

1. In the browser, get the dataURL, which is a base64 encoded string
2. send it in chunks to the database, where it'll be a CLOB
3. after everything has been sent, convert the CLOB to a BLOB and save
   it in your table